# Changing default JLabel font

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jlabel

How would I go about setting the default font for all `JLabel` instances. Instead of setting the font for each `JLabel` independently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`UIManager`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) to define JLabel's default font:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class LabelFont {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Font oldLabelFont = UIManager.getFont("Label.font");
      UIManager.put("Label.font", oldLabelFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));

      JFrame f = new JFrame("LabelFont Test");
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      JLabel df = new JLabel("Default JLabel font");
      f.getContentPane().add(df);

      JLabel ef = new JLabel("Font explicitly set");
      ef.setFont(oldLabelFont);
      f.getContentPane().add(ef);

      f.pack();
      f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Via: http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.help/2005-04/msg00395.html

Comment: i'm confused a bit. I tried to follow the same procedure as you all gusy doing. Using UIManager and then putting new JLabel.font properties with another Font type, but it seems uneffected on my pc.
Is there something wrong with this UIManager? :)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class LabelFont {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Font oldLabelFont = UIManager.getFont("Label.font");
      UIManager.put("Label.font", oldLabelFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));

      JFrame f = new JFrame("LabelFont Test");
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

      JLabel df = new JLabel("Default JLabel font");
      f.getContentPane().add(df);

      JLabel ef = new JLabel("Font explicitly set");
      ef.setFont(oldLabelFont);
      f.getContentPane().add(ef);

      f.pack();
      f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```