# JLabel html text ignores setFont

Tags: java, html, swing, fonts, jlabel

I've just started porting my Swing app from OS X to Windows and things are painful with `JLabel`s.

I've noticed that the font specified to `setFont` is ignored if the label's text is HTML (this doesn't happen on the Mac).  The HTML formatting is EXTREMELY useful for readability on complicated displays.

Under normal circumstances I'd specify the font in an HTML tag, but the font I'm using is loaded at runtime using `Font.createFont` with a ttf out of the JAR.  I tried using the loaded font's name in the font tag, but that didn't work.

Is there any way I can use a loaded `awt.Font` with an html-ified `JLabel` on Windows?

Here's an example.  I can't share my application's font, but I just ran it with this one (a pure TTF) and the same behavior happens:

http://www.dafont.com/sophomore-yearbook.font

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LabelTestFrame extends JFrame {

        public LabelTestFrame() throws Exception {
                boolean useHtml = true;
                String fontPath = "C:\\test\\test_font.ttf";
                JLabel testLabel = new JLabel();
                Font testFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(fontPath)).deriveFont(18f);
                testLabel.setFont(testFont);
                if (useHtml) testLabel.setText("<html>Some HTML'd text</html>");
                else testLabel.setText("Some plaintext");
                getContentPane().add(testLabel);
                setSize(300,300);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                try {new LabelTestFrame().setVisible(true);}
                                catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                        }
                });
        }

}
```

EDIT: interestingly enough, if I use one of the ttf's from the JRE's lib/fonts folder (in this case one of the Lucida fonts here renamed to test_java.ttf) this snippet produces identical results with the boolean on and off.

```
public LabelTestFrame() throws Exception {
    boolean useHtml = false;
    String fontPath = "C:\\test\\test_java.ttf";
    JLabel testLabel = new JLabel();
    Font testFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(fontPath)).deriveFont(18f);
    testLabel.setFont(testFont);
    if (useHtml) testLabel.setText("<html><b>Some HTML'd text</b></html>");
    else testLabel.setText("Some plaintext");
    getContentPane().add(testLabel);
    setSize(300,300);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {new LabelTestFrame().setVisible(true);}
            catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT 2:  The method described here for setting the default JLabel font has exactly the same problem (plaintext shows fine, html'd text doesn't):  [Changing default JLabel font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966296/changing-default-jlabel-font)

EDIT 3:  I've noticed that even random fonts from dafont will work if they're installed on the system (even with this exact code, where I'm loaded a copy of the [now installed] ttf from a file).

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org)? In the meantime, if you haven't already, read the [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) tutorial.

Comment: It is highly likely that you `Font.createFont` is having issues. `Jlabel`'s `setFont()` is guaranteed to set the font - as @mre suggests, the example would help to answer this better.

Comment: I know that Font.createFont works because if I setText("example") on the JLabel the loaded font shows up, but if I setText("<html>example</html>") the default Swing JLabel font is used.  Does this count as an sscce?

Comment: thanks for the clarification, just posted one!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`registerFont()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#registerFont%28java.awt.Font%29)

I found this little gem while Googling about if I could copy a `.ttf` into the JRE at runtime.  It does exactly what it's supposed to.  If you use `Font.createFont` to load a font at runtime, just do:

`GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(myCreatedFont)`

to register it with the JRE.

This allows the font to show up in HTML'd text as well as plaintext on Windows!

Comment: +1 [`createFont()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29) mentions this, but it's a little vague.

Comment: It only mentions it in the Java 6 javadoc.  Damn you Google for showing 1.4's javadoc first!

Comment: Can't blame Google for the Snoracle Shuffle! :-)

Answer (score 4):

For reference, here's what is seen on Mac OS X.

[image]

By comparison, here's the display on Ubuntu 10, OpenJDK 6.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LabelTestFrame extends JFrame {

    public LabelTestFrame() throws Exception {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        String fontPath = "SophomoreYearbook.ttf";
        Font testFont = Font.createFont(
            Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(fontPath)).deriveFont(18f);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("<html>Some HTML'd text</html>");
        label1.setFont(testFont);
        this.add(label1);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Some plaintext");
        this.add(label2);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new LabelTestFrame().setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping an easy side-by-side comparison might shed light. Does _any_ `.ttf` file work on Windows?

Comment: yeah, the builtin (already JRE installed) Lucida ttf does the right thing for me.  It looks like Linux is breaking for you, too (is it Sun Java or OpenJDK?).

Comment: where did platform independence go?? :)

Comment: OpenJDK; is this a problem for particular fonts, then?

Comment: I think the builtin JRE fonts are pre-registered with the system or something.  I haven't gotten any TTF obtained anywhere else to work.

Comment: @Ryan N are you see those Fonts in List of Fonts in Native OS or accesible for example in OpenOffice, MailBox, Internet_WWW_Viewer or another installed SW

Comment: @mKorbel, I'm trying to load ttf's that aren't installed on the system from a file at runtime.

Comment: not possible as I know, lots of Instaled SW required instaled Font in Native OS, and Java especially, that's my knowledge from another Forums, where all answerer asked at first if is Font instaled in the Native OS