# How to change font size of all private JLabels

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jlabel

I have seen similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966296/changing-default-jlabel-font), but in my case I have 25+ private JLabels that I give a value for when I declare it. I use a GridBagLayout in my constructor to add these JLabels to a JPanel. If I use something along the lines of the answer given in the link, it will only change JLabels that were added in the constructor.

So it seems to me that if I want to change the font size of my private JLabels, I would have to either define the font size for them individually, or change the default in my constructor and *then* add my JLabels. However, I am sure that there must be another, simpler way, but I just don't have the experience or understanding to figure it out, or to make proper adjustments from answers to other similar questions.

I don' think that this really requires me to show my code, but if it helps I can do so.

```
public class LaborRecordPanel implements
Printable, ActionListener {

private Color shade = new Color(201,201,201);

private ImageIcon logoIcon = new ImageIcon("Images/fici_logo1.jpg");
private JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel(logoIcon);

private JLabel authorizedBy = new JLabel("AUTHORIZED BY:");
private JLabel toCertify = new JLabel("THIS IS TO CERTIFY THAT THE ABOVE LABOR HAS BEEN PERFORMED.");

private JLabel laborRecordNO = new JLabel("NO.");
private JLabel nameOfJob = new JLabel("NAME OF JOB:");
private JLabel customerPO = new JLabel("CUSTOMER PO #:");
private JLabel contractNO = new JLabel("CONTRACT NO.");
private JLabel weekEnding = new JLabel("WEEK ENDING");
private JComboBox laborRateDescription = new JComboBox();
//...

JPanel rp = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(rp);
LaborRecordPanel(){
    //Font oldLabelFont = UIManager.getFont("Label.font");
    //UIManager.put("Label.font",oldLabelFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN));
    //UIManager.put("Label.font", UIManager.getFont("Label.font").deriveFont(40));
    //SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(rp);
    rp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1295,1830 ));
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16); //increase the scroll speed

    GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
    rp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    rp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    rp.setLayout(gridbag);
    //gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

    //row 0////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.gridx = 10;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    laborRecordNO.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    laborRecordNO.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    gridbag.setConstraints(laborRecordNO, gbc);
    rp.add(laborRecordNO, gbc);

    //row 1////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 13;
    gridbag.setConstraints(logoLabel, gbc);
    rp.add(logoLabel, gbc);

    //row 2////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gridbag.setConstraints(nameOfJob, gbc);
    rp.add(nameOfJob, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 6;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    gridbag.setConstraints(contractNO, gbc);
    rp.add(contractNO, gbc);
 //... more setting constraints and adding
 }
 }
```

Comment: Please show us the code!

Comment: absolutely, one minute please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the `UIManager` default for labels. It may be more aesthetic to use `deriveFont()` on the existing default. The change should be made *before* constructing the GUI using `EventQueue.invokeLater()`.

```
Font f = (Font) UIManager.get("Label.font");
UIManager.put("Label.font", f.deriveFont(36f));
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {…}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @trashgod, I am not very familiar with EventQueues so I'll have to research that more before I can ask any further questions regarding your suggestion

Comment: @solleks: Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the size of some of your JLabels to a variable select size during GUI creation, then you could use a factory method of some sort.

```
private JLabel createLabel(String text, float points) {
  JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
  label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(points));
  return label;
}
```

If you want to change them on the fly as the program is running, then put them in a `List<JLabel>` and give the GUI class a public method that allows the labels font sizes to be changed in a for loop.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So if I use your first suggestion, I would do that for every label? for example: "label" = nameOfJob, "text"=NAME OF JOB, points=18.

Comment: @solleks: if you want to do it for *every* label, then use the other suggestions such as that of Nullpointer or trashgod.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you only have `JLable`s in your code:

This will do the trick!

```
setUIFont(new FontUIResource(new Font("Arial", 0, 20)));
```

This will set `Arial` as a font, 20 as a size for all the Elements!

Comment: thanks for your answer @Nullpointer. I think the problem I would have with this though is that it would only change JLabels that I created within my constructor and not the JLabels that I defined beforehand, such as nameOfJob and weekEnding.