# JCheckBox: Vertical alignment for multi-line text

Tags: java, swing, vertical-alignment, jcheckbox

I have come across a slight visual issue in Java (swing) when using custom fonts with a JCheckBox. I have a JCheckBox with text spanning multiple lines. When using the default font, it looks fine. However, when I use a custom font (imported on-the-fly from a .ttf file), the vertical alignment seems to be slightly offset, making it look ugly. The text accompanying the checkbox should be slightly *higher* than it appears.

Is there any way to tweak the vertical position of the checkbox its text label? This happens when I use this code to align the checkbox at the top: `checkbox.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TOP)`

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the default font? Size? Pitch? Style? Available glyphs?

Comment: @trashgod Size + style, I suppose. I'd just like to use a different font. I'm using this font for the rest of my UI, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each platform specifies *physical* fonts to use for the defined *logical* [`Font`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) families. These fonts have well-defined metrics that are known to be compatible with the host platform. Using an odd-lot font puts you at the mercy of the font's designer and the platform's implementation of font hints. Instead, use the `UIManager` to *derive* the desired size and style *before* constructing the GUI, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21734043/230513).

Comment: Thanks for responding. The font I'm using is Roboto, which is a fairly common font, so I figured it should work fine with swing. I tried doing what you said, but it only seems to change the size/style of the font - the problem still persists.

Comment: Right, the problem is in how the platform _applies_ the font, using the metrics it gets from the host OS. In addition to style & size, you can apply an `AffineTransform`.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of AffineTransform - I tried applying a translation to the font to offset its position. For whatever reason, it seemed to work on all the text in my program EXCEPT the checkbox's label. Anyways, I found a workaround solution - I used a checkbox and a separate, which seems to work better with this font, for whatever reason.

Comment: You are welcome; glad you got it sorted. If you go with the separate label, look at `JLabel#setLabelFor()`.